# How Daisy Chaining Monitors work?

Tags: displayport, daisychaining

Can this only be done with Display Port 1.2? Can someone please explain how does this works?

Also, Dell u2713H supports Daisy Chaining, what advantage this support mean? Can I connect 3 2560x1440 displays to my Base 2011 Mac Mini?

Answer (score 1):

Display port 1.2_4 supports daisy chaining multiple monitors, it appears to be independent of source, but your graphics card must support it, so once you find out what video card is in your mac mini then you can visit the manufacturer's site to find out.

ftp://ftp.dell.com/Manuals/all-products/esuprt_electronics/esuprt_Display/dell-u2713h_User%27s%20Guide_en-us.pdf

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DisplayPort

Comment: My Mac Mini have Intel HD 3000. The new Mac Mini got Intel HD 4000. So, can I connect 2 displays to my own and 3 to the new one?

Answer (score 0):

I was running into issues daisy chaining my monitors as well.

Hardware: Dell U3415W and U2717D

After looking at some forums and documentation I realized that there cannot be different display interfaces in the chain.

https://www.dell.com/support/kbdoc/en-us/000128707/how-to-daisy-chain-multiple-monitors-using-displayport-multi-stream-transport-mst

For example:

**Failing Configuration** --> Dell Dock --> (HDMI Cable) --> U3415W Monitor --> (DP Cable) --> U2717D Monitor

**Working Configuration** --> Dell Dock --> (DP Cable) --> U3415W Monitor --> (DP Cable) --> U2717D Monitor

Hope this helps!